# Encode PCMBuffer to Ogg with Opus in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ogg, opus

I need to encode raw audio into ogg packets with opus codec.

I get the raw audio like that:

```
    input.installTapOnBus(0, bufferSize: 2048, format: input.inputFormatForBus(0)) { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!, time: AVAudioTime!) -> Void in

        // Encode buffer to Ogg
    }
```

I have Ogg.framework and libopus.a in my project. I don't seem to understand the documentation how to actually use Opus with Ogg. And I didn't find any example that replicates what I need.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I created a repository for this: https://github.com/Devxhkl/SwiftAudioStreamingOggOpus

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two options:

1. Create some wrapper for [opusenc](https://github.com/xiph/libopusenc) library for encoding PCM in Ogg/Opus. This library is written in pure C but well structered and easy to use. Just look at the example "examples/opusenc_example.c"
2. Hijack some code from [watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk) it contains [decoder](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk/blob/master/Source/TextToSpeechV1/TextToSpeechDecoder.swift) and [encoder](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk/blob/master/Source/SpeechToTextV1/WebSockets/SpeechToTextEncoder.swift) for OGG/OPUS based on [libopus](https://github.com/xiph/opus) and [ogg](https://github.com/xiph/ogg).